# DataTable Column Reorder maps data in wrong columns

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatables

I have made following JSBIn in which you can see the code. Due to CORS policy the ajax url I used is not working but it generates following output in which you can see see data is mapped in wrong columns. Please let me know using same data object column names which I have used how to fix this?

[image: ata]

https://jsbin.com/ciheragayi/1/edit?html,css,js,output

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": "https://a.uguu.se/8MdQchH6NKHJ_CYF.txt",
      "processing": true,

        "serverSide": true,
        colReorder: true,

        "columns": [
            { "data": "0" },
            { "data": "1" },
            { "data": "2" },
            { "data": "3" },
            { "data": "4" },
            { "data": "5" }
        ],
      colReorder: {
            order: [ 3,5,2,4,1,0 ]
        },
    } );
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful in using

```
colReorder: {
    order: [ 3,5,2,4,1,0]
}
```

The order would be DATE-ID- SALARY-COUNTRY-POSITION-NAME
3 represents "3" in this JSON Object and so on and so forth

```
 {
      "0": "Tiger Nixon",
      "1": "System Architect",
      "2": "$320,800",
      "3": "2011/04/25",
      "4": "Edinburgh",
      "5": "5421"
    }
```

It's either you adjust the header or you adjust the colReorder or your columns,
use this configuration for columns adjustments

```
        "columns": [
            { "data": "0" },
            { "data": "1" },
            { "data": "4" },
            { "data": "5" },
            { "data": "3" },
            { "data": "2" }
        ]
```

Comment: Josh, Thank you for your answer, why the TH is not getting reordered? I have to give  the Columns name in sequence. Also. is there a way to give the column order after the datatable get initialized?

Comment: It's getting reordered, we declared our th in html in this order name-position-Office-Extn-Start date-Salary.

Since we tell datatables to rearrange our columns, with colReorder {order: [ 3,5,2,4,1,0]}
this means 3(Extn) will be the first column, 5(Salary) will be the second, and so on and so forth.


yes, by doing table.colReorder.order( [ 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0 ] ) where table is 
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
Here's a bin for your reference
https://jsbin.com/pewumajebu/1/edit?html,js,output